# how to add custom sound in iOS with flutter?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification

I am new to push notifications and I have this task to add a custom sound whenever the user receives a notification. I am not using flutter local notifications, just the normal firebase configurations and its working well. Can anyone help me add a custom sound for iOS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the payload used and the firebase configurations.

```
options = { 
    "notification": {
      "title": formatter.title,
      "body": formatter.body,
      "sound": "notification.caf",
      "content_available": true,
    },
     "priority": "high",
     "data": {
        "badge": user.unopened_notification_count,
        "body": formatter.body,
        "title": formatter.title,
        "id": notification.id,
        "notifiable_type": notification.notifiable_type,
        "notifiable_id": notification.notifiable_id,
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
     }
  }
```

also here is my firebase configuration:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.data['id']}');
}

handleNotifications() async {
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(badge: false, alert: false, sound: true); //presentation options for Apple notifications when received in the foreground.

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
    print('Got a message whilst in the FOREGROUND!');
    return;
  }).onData((data) async {
    print('Got a DATA message whilst in the FOREGROUND!');
    print('data from stream: ${data.data['id']}');
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) async {
    print('NOTIFICATION MESSAGE TAPPED');
    return;
  }).onData((data) async {
    print('NOTIFICATION MESSAGE TAPPED');
    print('data from stream: ${data.data}');
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) => value != null ? _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler : false);
  return;
}
```

attached image here is where I placed the sound file inside Xcode
[image]

[image]